# Something like mathoverflow in other sciences

Tags: soft-question, computer-science, st.statistics, physics, economics

Are the sites similar to mathoverflow in other sciences related to mathematics? statistics, computer science, physics, economics, etc?

Let me explain what I mean by "similar": those are sites devoted to posing questions and answers,in these areas. I do not insist on the precise format of "mathoverflow" (reputation points, badges, etc.). But I am looking for general multi-participants forums like this one, so scientific blogs do not qualify.

Comment: This question belongs on http://meta.stackexchange.com, where it has this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites/5#5

Comment: well, I disagree; I did not ask about this specific format with rhe reputation points and bronze medals but about various other platforms for questions and answers in areas related to mathematics...

Comment: "Similar" is not very specific, so I hope you can see how I misunderstood. There are lots of forum sites in the sciences, like http://www.physicsforums.com/. Another thing to look for is blogs, which tend to have a different flavor of questions/answers, but have the downside that very few people can make a new post; there's a massive list of academic blogs at http://wiki.henryfarrell.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page. I'm sure there are also wikis in the other sciences akin to http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage and http://www.tricki.org/, but I don't know about them.

Comment: I remember there where discussion forums on physics and maybe also on math but I do nt remember the details. the stackexchanges forums on physics and science are still rather undeveloped.

Comment: Please have a look at http://www.voofie.com/. You can post discussions like a forum, ask questions, post articles or link on a specific topics. For instance, if you go to concept page of http://www.voofie.com/concept/Mathematics/, you get something like a Maths forum. While it is an all in one site, you can gain points(impact factor) in each specific areas, and higher your points, higher your power in the related field.

Comment: I raised a somewhat related question on meta: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/440/can-weshould-we-try-to-attract-scientists-from-other-fields-to-mo/

Comment: It seems like this is very much a "meta" question about the idea of MathOverflow rather than about the things MathOverflow is about. 

Comment: Dear Ryan, the purpose of this question is to allow quick access to Questions-and-Answers sites in neighboring areas to mathematics which can be of interest to mathematicians. So it is a question like "where can I find ICM talks" or "what are journals for research in mathematical economics". So I dont think it is a meta question about the idea of MO.  (But perhaps if there will be permanent often updated links to such sites on MO it need not be a question at all). 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a brief list of science-related sites that run on the same platform as Math Overflow:

- Science

  - [Science Stack](http://sciencestack.com/)
  - [asksci.com](http://asksci.com/)
- Physics

  - [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
  - [PhysicsOverflow](http://physicsoverflow.org/)
- Electronics

  - [Electronics Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
- Programming

  - [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

A complete list of these sites is available [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites/5#5).

The one thing that I personally feel is missing is a lower-level mathematics site (a Math Underflow, if you will).  I understand the desire to keep Math Overflow relevant and interesting for professional mathematicians, but there is currently no equivalent site for amateurs and students.

**Update:** (Sept 2010)A math site for [university level mathematics exists now](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

There are also sites for [theoretical computer science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) and for [statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

(April 2011) There is a [TEX Q/A site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)!

(September 2011) [Area 51: science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science) contains new proposed stackexchange sites related to science. We can mention especially proposals for [Theoretical physics (and mathematical physics)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics) (closed), economics (closed), research economics, game theory, [computational sciences](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) (the site is running), [numerical models and simulations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1907/numerical-modeling-and-simulation), Mathematica, mathematics in german.

Comment: NRICH, AoPS etc should fill the need for amateurs and students.

Comment: Not really, there's definitely room for a StackExchange site for the freshman-calculus-type questions that get closed so quickly on this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very useful. Actually my question was not just for sites in the same format but also on sites for questions and discussions of similar nature with other formats.

Comment: @las3rjock: you can always start a new SE site if you think it will work (http://beta.stackexchange.com/sign-up). It's free until it comes out of beta (and for another 30-45 days after that). The problem is that to have a successful SE site, you need both askers and answerers. From the point of view of the calculus student, it would be nice to have a place to go to get your questions answered, but who is going to answer them? By it's very nature, a calculus forum is something you get sick of once you've learned calculus well enough. Then again, I could be wrong; I haven't tried the experiment.

Comment: I find it sad that all these other sites are really anemic compared to Mathoverflow, which is itself much smaller than Stackoverflow but still definitely suited to the needs its called on to meet.

A (>miniscule) physicsoverflow, econoverflow and computer science (not programming) overflow would all be really helpful.

Comment: There is also [MetaOptimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/) for AI, ML, ... 

Comment: There is MathStackExchange.

Comment: Someone added physicsoverflow, but it doesn't "run on the same platform as Math Overflow". The introduction should be changed to refer to that, I think -- it doesn't really matter if a site uses SE rather than q2a as software backend.

Answer (score 6):

Well, MathOverflow is based on Stack Overflow, which is about programming -- though not, perhaps, computer science in an academic sense.  Good question, though!

My guess is that such sites would tend to degenerate quite quickly unless the subject lends itself to questions which **can** be answered.  Such questions tend to be predominantly mathematical, perhaps by definition, so perhaps they could be incorporated into MathOverflow.  Already we are seeing an increasing number of questions on mathematical physics.

Comment: Thanks! here is the link to stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Actually most questions which can be answered are definitely not mathematical. Stackoverflow exists (if memory surves right) almost a year and a half, and has 70K users, and 360K questions. The guy who evnisioned it - Joel Spolsky - simply wanted a place to ask technical questions instead of reading a lot of ducmentation, or start looking for techn support; it would probably serve very similar purposes in say medicine or chemistry. You should probably look for cultural reasons if you want to find out how come mathematicians are the first to follow the stackoverlow example.

Comment: Point taken.  Bibliographical questions can be readily answered in any field, as can some questions in fields based on factual knowledge.